# JPL Ephemeris or Skyfield - how to get moon phase percentage (not illumination percentage)

Tags: the-moon, software, moon-phases

I know how to use [JPL's Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) to get `moon illumination percentage` but I noticed that even at new moon, the illumination never goes to zero:

```
b0003-Sep-09 12:10 *m    0.07382  
b0003-Sep-09 12:11 *m    0.07382  
b0003-Sep-09 12:12 *m    0.07381  
b0003-Sep-09 12:13 *m    0.07381
```

I *could* just normalize relative to the lowest illumination percentage but I would prefer to have the JPL site, or some Python package like [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/), spit out: **the moon phase percentage is 0% at date, time = x, y**

Comment: Naively, it seems like if the moon would only reach 0% illumination during a solar eclipse. Maybe you can find a software package to compute when solar eclipses occured?

Comment: Horizons gives you the correct illumination, which is based on the 3D angle between the Sun & Moon. As I said [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50592/tool-to-calculate-moonrise-moonset-and-moon-phase-for-any-date-for-any-location#comment112661_50592), the principle lunar phases (New Moon, First Quarter, Full Moon, Last Quarter) use the angle between the Sun & Moon in the ecliptic plane.

Comment: FWIW, the next Full Moon is on 2022-Oct-09 20:54:58.918 UTC. That's geocentric, so it ignores parallax & atmospheric refraction.

Comment: You should probably clarify if you're looking for the phase % or the illumination %, they are different things.  Illumination uses 3D angles, while the phase uses only 2D angles (specifically, the angles in the ecliptic plane).

Comment: @GregMiller I thought I was clear: “moon phase percentage”. I’ll add “not illumination” to the question.

Comment: @Bob looking at the [Horizons Manual](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html) I see percent illuminated and phase angle, I don't see "moon phase percentage" and I've never heard of that term. You use it in the title of your question, but you say "moon illumination percentage" in the body of your question, so while *you thought you were clear* I think you still need to clarify, and if you want stick with  "moon phase percentage" you'll need to explain what that means either by defining it yourself or adding a link to a formal definition.

Comment: @uhoh I *think* Bob wants: New Moon=0%, First Quarter=25%, Full Moon=50%, Last Quarter=75%. Or maybe he wants Full Moon=100%...

Comment: @PM2Ring oh I see. Ya since that's a 2D universe concept there's no perfect proxy in a real-world problem.

Comment: The phase percentage would just be the phase angle divided by 360deg.